# Using Laplace for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, laplace-transform

The transverse displacement $u(x, t)$ of a semi-infinite elastic string satisfies:
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$

$ x > 0,  t > 0$
with initial conditions
$$u(x,0) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,0) = 0$$ 
$x > 0$

and boundary condition
$$\beta \frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(0,t) = f(t)$$ 
$t > 0$.
Show, using Laplace transforms that the solution can be written as:
($H(x)$ is the Heaviside function)

$$u(x,t) = \frac{c}{\beta}H\left(t - \frac{x}{c}\right) \int_{0}^{t - x/c}f(u)du$$

Can you interpret this result physically?

I'm struggling to get the answer and need some help. Let me know if there are any typos.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Did you start using the Laplace transform and turn the problem into a BVP?

Comment: @LordVader007 I found that $U = Ae^{sx/c}+ Be^{-sx/c}$ where $U =L(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}) $ $(L(f(t)) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}f(t)dt)$. Not sure how to apply condition to arrive at the final solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L$ be the Laplace transform. Take the Laplace transform of both sides of the PDE to get:

$L({\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}})$ = $L(c^2 \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2})$ $\implies$ $s^2U(s,x) - su(x,0)-u_t(x,0)$ = $c^2 \frac{\partial^2U}{\partial x^2}$

Apply the initial conditions above to get:

$s^2U(s,x)$ = $c^2 \frac{\partial^2U}{\partial x^2}$ $\implies$ $\frac{s^2}{c^2}U(s,x)$ = $ \frac{\partial^2U}{\partial x^2}$

Since we only have $x$, we can think of this as an ODE (eliminate dependency on time variable):

$\frac{s^2}{c^2}U(x)$ = $ \frac{\partial^2U(x)}{\partial x^2}$

From here, you should be able to solve the above as a BVP, with the boundary condition given as $-\beta u_x(0,t) = f(t)$

Take Laplace transform of the BC:

$L(-\beta u_x(0,t)) = -\beta L(u_x(0,t)) = L(f(t)) \implies -\beta \frac{dU(0,s)}{dx} =F(s) \implies \frac{dU(0,s)}{dx}= -\frac{F(s)}{\beta}$

Use the general solution you got to get that:

$\frac{dU(0,s)}{dx} = A \frac{s}{c} -B \frac{s}{c} = -\frac{F(s)}{\beta} \implies A -B = -\frac{cF(s)}{s\beta}$

By definition of the Laplace transform, we may write:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}u(x,t)dt =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-st}u(x,t)dt =0$$

From this, you may deduce that the first coefficient is zero, since $c>0$  and for fixed $s>0$, the function $e^{\frac{sx}{c}}$ increases as $x$ increases.

From here, it follows that $U(x,s) = Be^{\frac{-sx}{c}} = \frac{cF(s)}{s\beta} e^{\frac{-sx}{c}}$ and so we arrive at the answer.

So we needed a further assumption on the solution $U(x,s)$, which says that as $x \rightarrow \infty$, then $U(x,s) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Can you go a few more steps? I was stuck around here. Not sure how to take laplace of conditions.

Comment: Check it now...

Comment: For finding the equation, A + B = 0, don't we need the condition u(0,t) = 0? This wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: $u(x,s) =L^{-1} (\frac{cF(s)}{2s\beta}(e^{\frac{xs}{c}} -e^{-\frac{xs}{c}})) = \frac{c}{2\beta} L^{-1} (F(s)) * (  L^{-1} (e^{\frac{xs}{c}} -e^{-\frac{xs}{c}})) = \frac{c}{2\beta} f(t) * ( H(t +x/c) -H(t -x/c))$,

Comment: How does this statement turn out to be the u(x,t) function as mentioned above. where * represents the convolution. @LordVader007

Comment: Just caught a mistake, check again now.

Comment: $A + B =0 \implies A = -\frac{cF(s)}{2s\beta}, B=\frac{cF(s)}{2s\beta}$.  and $U_s(x,0) = A\frac{x}{s}- B\frac{x}{s} = 0 \implies A-B=0$ Combine this with the equation $A +B=0$ to get that $A = 0$ so $B = \frac{cF(s)}{s\beta}$.

Comment: Just wondering about these two parts. If we combine $$A - B = 0 $$ and $A+B = 0$, don't we get $ A = 0 $ and $B = 0$?    @LordVader007

Comment: I did a bit of digging around to see why we were getting ^. It turns out you need to know further properties of the Laplace transform, especially it's behavior as x gets larger and larger. See https://www.ijsr.net/archive/v4i2/SUB151721.pdf for more.